# Unreal Engine - How can I add blur effect at my Camera in iOS

Tags: ios, unreal-4, effect

I have requirement to add blur effect at my camera in specific point , it work just fine in pc but when I deploy in my phone it remove the effect

According to [documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Platforms/Mobile/PostProcessEffects/index.html#depthoffield)

> To turn off Depth of Field, set "Scale" to zero, this is suggested as
>   default to improve performance.
>
> Mobile Depth of Field is currently not compatible with PC. There is no
>   way to currently visualize on the desktop version what the mobile
>   settings will look like except using an unsupported "-FeatureLevelES2"
>   launch flag when starting the editor, or using the "Mobile Preview"
>   option from the "Play" button drop down menu.

But when I run in my mobile this effect disappear

any one know the reason

here is my Camera setting

[image]